# Almost complex structure compatible with Levi-Civita connection of immersed submanifold?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, connections

Suppose we have Riemannian manifold $M$ isometrically immersed in a Kähler manifold $\tilde{M}$. Let $\tilde{g}$ be the metric and $\tilde{\nabla}$ the Levi-Civita connection on $\tilde{M}$ , we know that the isometric immersion defines a metric $g$ on $M$ which then has a Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$. Now, the Kähler manifold has an almost complex structure $J$ for which holds that

> $$ \tilde{\nabla}_XJY = J\tilde{\nabla}_XY $$

However, does the same hold for $J$ and $\nabla$?

> $$ \nabla_XJY = J\nabla_XY $$

I would assume so since $\tilde{\nabla}$ and $\nabla$ are related through the immersion somehow, but I don't quite know how to prove this. And if it does not hold in general, are there conditions for which it does hold? (Totally real, holomorphic, minimal, ...)

Comment: Unless you impose further conditions on $M$ and the immersion, the question probably doesn't make sense. Why should $TM$ be $J$-invariant if $M$ isn't a complex submanifold?

Comment: I'm quite a beginner in Riemannian Geometry, so I hope you don't mind any stupid questions, but... does TM have to be J-invariant for this question to make sense? The particular case I really need (though I'm interested in the more general statement) is if $M$ is totally real, minimal and of constant seciontal curvature, and $\tilde{M}$ is a complex space form, then
$\langle Jh(X,Y),Z \rangle = \langle Jh(X,Z),Y\rangle$
with $h$ the second fundamental form of the immersion. What I stated in the question is (according to my calculations) sufficient to prove this.

Comment: Well, as it stands, you were applying $\nabla$ to $JY$, so you'd need $JY$ to be tangent to $M$. I think you'll need to stick with $\tilde\nabla$ in general? The second fundamental form, after all, comes from using $\tilde\nabla$.

Comment: Ah, of course, that makes sense, $\nabla$ would not be defined on $(T_pM)^\perp$. However, $\nabla_X Y \in TM$ so $\langle \nabla_XY,JZ\rangle = 0$, exactly because $\nabla_XY$ lies in $TM$, I think? Then that should in fact be enough to prove the theorem I want, with the added condition that $M$ is totally real.